# Need conditional statement to only load script if not IE8 or before and not mobile device

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I have a link to a script in the head section of my page in the traditional format, i.e.

```
<script src="scripts/scriptname.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I would like to prevent this script loading in IE8 and earlier and also on iPhones/iPads and mobile devices in general.

I have this statement for preventing it running in IE8, but I am not sure how to adapt this to include earlier versions of IE as well, and I am also not sure about mobile devices:

```
<!--[if !IE 8]><!-->
    <script src="scripts/scriptname.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Could someone help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="scripts/scriptname.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

this will include the block for Internet Explorer 8 and lower ( lt = less than ).

But - if you have to adapt the script just for mobile devices too, i think a javascript solution is the best.
Check the user agent by the navigator object for browser and device, like this:

```
if( (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || ... )
```

Include all mobile devices can be too much. Switch by the screen size is a good way:

```
if ( screen.width <= 699 ) {
     // your script
}
```

with browser detection for finding MSIE but not 9.0:

```
if ( screen.width <= 699 || navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/) ) {
     // your script
}
```