# HTML IF IE 8 and lower and IF NOT IE 8 and lower

Tags: html, internet-explorer, if-statement

Is my syntax correct below?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{"/js/photo_carousel_ie.js"}"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{"/js/photo_carousel.js"}"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

What I am trying to do is, if IE 8 and lower user ie js file, if any other browser except IE 8 and lower, use the regular js file.

Comment: Why don't you try it? put an alert() into both js files to say which one they are, and then try the page in ie8 and ie9.

Comment: Do you have a particular problem with your code?

Comment: The type attribute has not been needed in browsers for quite some time and defaults to 'text/javascript'.

Comment: I assume you also need other browsers like Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc. to read this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your script tags need to be valid html tags and having the curly braces are not valid.  Your code should look like this

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/photo_carousel_ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/photo_carousel.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can refer to this question/response for more information:
[Need conditional statement to only load script if not IE8 or before and not mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502975/need-conditional-statement-to-only-load-script-if-not-ie8-or-before-and-not-mobi)

Answer (score 3):

Only IE browsers read html comments. So to target other browsers, like Chrome and Firefox, you need to put your comments like below. This way, IE browsers will read the comments, but the code is readable by the other browsers.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/photo_carousel_ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/photo_carousel.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="//s3.amazonaws.com/nwapi/nwmatcher/nwmatcher-1.2.5-min.js"></script>
  <script src="//html5base.googlecode.com/svn-history/r38/trunk/js/selectivizr-1.0.3b.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.1.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```